# How to format output of system function PHP?

Tags: php

I use function `system()` to run system process.

```
$buff = system('python excel.py ' . $handle->file_dst_pathname, $retval);
```

It displays messages in line without separations.

In Python I use this line to print data:

```
 print "# %d - article \"%s\" was inserted!" % (i, article)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precede the output of `system(...);` with `echo "<pre>";` and follow with `echo "</pre>";`

Or shorter:

```
$buff = "<pre>" . system('python excel.py ' . $handle->file_dst_pathname, $retval) . "</pre>";
```

You could also change all the `"\n"` chars of your output into `"<br/>"`.